# Cocoa Nibs for Chocolate Flavorings

Tags: flavor, additives, steeping, boil

What is the best way to use cocoa nibs?
Do you crush them, crack them leave them whole?
Steep and remove pre-boil, leave in boil, add at flameout?
Add them only during secondary?  How long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that using them just like a dry hop works well. Throw them in to secondary and you should be able to rack your beer out without picking up any nibs. **(I have heard of people calling it dry nibbing)*

Answer (score 3):

Roast the nibs to bring out their flavor then use them in the secondary.  Roast like you would coffee or in a heavy skillet over medium heat until fragrant and flavorful.